# Can't mount external Hard Drive after shrinking partition with parted

Tags: mount, partition, windows, ntfs, parted

I resized the NTFS partition in my external hard drive by shrinking it and then I created a 2nd fat32 partition starting from the end of the 1st partition. I also switched the boot flag from the NTFS partition to the FAT32 partition.

After quitting parted, the new FAT32 partition automounts when plugged in but the 1st NTFS partition can't be mounted using either `udisksctl` or manual mounting. The latter gives me:

```
[user@host mnt]# mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/volume
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to calculate free MFT records: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
```

I've tried `ntfsfix /dev/sdX` to repair the ntfs partition, the output below says it fixed the problem, but I still can't mount it:

```
    [user@host mnt]# ntfsfix /dev/sdd1
Mounting volume... Failed to read last sector (976769198): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to read last sector (976769198): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
Failed to read last sector (976769198): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Trying the alternate boot sector
The alternate bootsector is usable
Set sector count to 937497952 instead of 976769199
Rewriting the bootsector
The boot sector has been rewritten

Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... FIXED
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdd1 was processed successfully.
```

- Could it be the flag I changed or is it the shrinking and growing which is causing this problem?
- The end size shown by `parted` was different to what `fdisk` and `lsblk` showed. The latter was 465G while `parted` showed 500G so it was a bit confusing which one to follow. I ended up using 500G because I was using `parted` not `fdisk`.
- Are there any known solutions to restoring the partition so that it can be mounted again?

### update

Tried `chkdisk /f` and `chkdisk /r` in windows and `"I'm getting corrupt master file table, chkdsk aborted"`.

Comment: Did you remember to resize the NTFS filesystem before you shrank the partition it lived in?

Comment: You can try building a Windows VM using MS's free VM images, and use disk manager in the VM to figure what's wrong with the partition.

Comment: @jw013 the NTFS filesystem was the only partition in the hard drive. Thats why I dont understand why there are problems. I shrank the NTFS partition from 500G down to 480G and then created a fat32 partition from 480G all the way to the end.

Comment: @ajeh I am in windows right now. Disk manager shows the file system as raw and when I click on it it returns "the file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Comment: Partitions and file systems are different things. It sounds like you forgot or were not aware of that and only resized the partition without shrinking the filesystem first. It's like when the magician puts an assistant in the box and saws the box in half, only there is no magic here, the assistant is dead. If that is what you did your file system is destroyed and your best option is to recreate a new one and restore your files from backup.

Comment: I know the difference. @jw013 whats the command for resizing the file system? I followed this tutorial: [link](https://www.tecmint.com/parted-command-to-create-resize-rescue-linux-disk-partitions/) and it didn't mention anything about resizing the file system.

Comment: Your link is just a list of `parted` subcommands with examples but says nothing about how to use them properly do the task of shrinking a NTFS partition. In general to shrink a partition you would 1. back up the files somewhere else 2. shrink the file system (for NTFS that would be `ntfsresize`) and 3. shrink the partition. In your case if you forgot step 2 you cut off half the file system and overwrote it with a new FAT partition. This is generally not undoable, so your best option now is to restore from backup.

Comment: @jw013, I found the answer to my question [here](https://jfearn.fedorapeople.org/fdocs/en-US/Documentation/0.1/html/Fedora_Multiboot_Guide/freespace-ntfs.html). I find it astonishing that the previous link I posted didnt warn readers about resizing the filesystem first when the disk contains data.

Comment: @ jw013 spot on. Its clear now why `chkdsk` wouldn't even attempt to repair it.I have three questions, (1) will simply reformatting the disk avoid any future probles or do I have to use additional commands like `wipefs`. (2) The three steps you posted, do they also apply to a GUI tool like `GParted` when shrinking partitions or is it only for command line tools like `parted` and `fdisk` (3) Is the `fat32` partition fine as it is and can I only reformat the `NTFS` partition.

Comment: 1. Just creating a brand new NTFS file system is fine. The only reason you would do any wiping is if you didn't want any of the old data to be recoverable. 2. They apply in general but some tools like GParted may be able to do both steps 2 and 3 for some file system types. 3. Yes you can leave the FAT32 partition alone if it is working.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not quite sure about number 1. Would you recommend I recreate the `NTFS` filesystem or just skip that and format the already existing partition in `ntfs`? Your magician analogy makes me thing the actual partition may be damaged.

Comment: @ I started formatting the ntfs partition and for some reason its showing `Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Initializing device with zeroes`. I didn't explicity use the 'dd' command to write zeros from 'urandom' so why is it doing this. Do you know of a safe way to pause this process so that I can continue later., because it will take a long time?

Comment: The partition should be fine, it's just the file system (assistant) inside that was damaged. If you plug the drive into Windows and have Windows Disk Manager do a quick format of the shrunk partition it should be able to create a brand new NTFS file system in no time.

Comment: @jw013 I'm happy to report that it worked, I don't even have to use `udisksctl` to automount it`, saved me a bit of work. If you provide an answer I can select you and **Emmanuel Rosa's** answers. By the way is there a way to add a label to the partitions after they have been created? Right now its showing their UUID and its a bit jarring

Comment: Learn to use native tools first, and only use foreign tools when native are not available. Windows DM would have resized your NTFS partition fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could it be the flag I changed or is it the shrinking and growing which is causing this problem?

Your problem was caused by the shrinking and growing. Such operations are ALWAYS dangerous and thus if the data is important should never be done without backups on-hand.

> Are there any known solutions to restoring the partition so that it can be mounted again?

The best solution is to not bother restoring it and instead format the partition anew and restore your files from backup.

If that's not possible your second best option is to attempt fixing the partition within Windows.

Your third option is to delete the FAT partition and resize the NTFS partition back to the way it was. Maybe a second dose of `ntfsfix` will fix it after that, but by this point don't expect any miracles.

> ntfsfix is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems. ntfsfix is
>   NOT a Linux version of chkdsk. It only repairs some fundamental NTFS
>   inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS
>   consistency check for the first boot into Windows.
>
> You may run ntfsfix on an NTFS volume if you think it was damaged by
>   Windows or some other way and it cannot be mounted. - https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix

Comment: thanks. I will delete the fat32 partition and restore the NTFS filesystem back to its original size, then try ntfsfix one more time. If that doesn't work I will format the single partition and start afresh.

Comment: I tried windows `chkdsk /r /f` won't even attempt  to fix it, the process aborts. I'm trying option 1 now but the device is being initialised with zeroes so can't won't know for some time.